# Find sum of all values which overlap with multiple ranges perl

Tags: perl

I have two file structures as follows:

Intervals:

```
chr1    121087394   121087399
chr1    121087820   121087822
chr20   1934714     1934716
chr3    108047283   108047285
```

Depth:

```
chr1 121087395 A 3799
chr1 121087396 T 3818
chr1 121087397 G 3824
chr1 121087398 T 3827
chr1 121087399 G 3831
chr1 121087821 T 2499
chr1 121087822 T 2506
chr20 1934715  G 2650
chr20 1934716  T 2661
chr3 108047284 T 1755
chr3 108047285 C 1750
```

I want the output, where column 4 is sum of all values from column 4 of depth file falling in specific range.
Output:

```
    chr1 121087395 121087399 19099
    chr1 121087821 121087822 5005
    chr20 1934715  1934716   5331
    chr3  108047284 108047285 3505
```

My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $intervals = $ARGV[0];
my $depth = $ARGV[1];

my $args = $#ARGV+1;


my ($FI, $FD, @F, $i_chr, $i_start, $i_end, @diff, $i, $j);
my $z; 
my $nr=0;
my $sum=0;
open($FI, '<', $intervals) or die "Could not open file: $intervals\n";

while(<$FI>){
    chomp $_;
    ($i_chr, $i_start, $i_end) = split("\t", $_);
    open($FD, '<', $depth) or die "Could not open file: $depth\n";
    while(<$FD>){
    chomp $_;
    @F = split("\t", $_);
    if($F[0] eq $i_chr && $F[1] > $i_start && $F[1] <= $i_end){
        $nr++;
        $sum += $F[3];
    }
    }print "$sum\n";
}
```

The if loop is not working. It is printing the sum of all values of column 4 of depth file.

How can i modify this loop?

Comment: Post your sample file content, not an image of it.

Comment: You never reset `$sum` as you move onto next `$FI` iteration. So it keeps adding.

Comment: First read the depth-file into a suitable data structure, and use that to work with each line of the file with intervals. (Do you really need to process each line independently, even for same chr?) This way you open and iterate over depth-file anew for every single line of intervals-file.  (Can the depth-file be too large for your memory?)

Comment: Don't declare things up front; it is generally good, and important, to declare variables in as small a scope as possible. In your program most variables can be declared right as they are assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the numbers in your sample output don't match up with your description of what you're doing and the numbers in your sample input - things not adding up right, numbers out of range showing up, etc. so either your sample input, output, or description are wrong, and I'm not sure which. Plus, your sample code doesn't produce anything close to your expected output format (Which appears to be intended to be, for each interval range, the name, min and max depths in that range, and the sum of that last column)...

Still, this does what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use autodie;

# Read the depths file into a hash table to avoid re-reading it for
# every line of the intervals file.
my %depths;
open my $depth, "<", $ARGV[1];
while (<$depth>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split /\t/;
  push @{$depths{$F[0]}}, [ $F[1], $F[3] ];
}

open my $intervals, "<", $ARGV[0];
$, = "\t";
while (<$intervals>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split /\t/;
  my $sum = 0;
  my ($min, $max);
  for my $d (@{$depths{$F[0]}}) {
    if ($d->[0] >= $F[1] && $d->[0] <= $F[2]) {
      $sum += $d->[1];
      $min = $d->[0] if !defined $min || $d->[0] < $min;
      $max = $d->[0] if !defined $max || $d->[0] > $max;
    }
  }
  say $F[0], $min, $max, $sum;
}
```

Note all the things zdim mentioned in comments: the tighter scoping of variables (Leading to not keeping the previous values between new intervals), and only reading the depths file once, instead of once per line of the intervals file, making it a lot more efficient.

Comment: @zdim OP also has the first chr1 line sum as 19091 instead of 19099, and the chr3 line includes values from a row of the depths table that is out of range of the corresponding interval.

Comment: (fyi, it seems that the OP cleaned up the numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat similar to Shawn's solution, but instead of a hash of arrays, I used a hash of hashes. Also, I did not adjust the boundaries as Shawn did with `min` and `max`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %int;
open my $fh, '<', 'f2.txt' or die $!;
# depth file
while (<$fh>) {
    my ($chr, $num, $amt) = (split)[0,1,3];
    $int{$chr}{$num} = $amt;
}
close $fh or die $!;

open $fh, '<', 'f1.txt' or die $!;

# intervals file
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($chr, $start, $stop) = split;

    my $href = $int{$chr}; # hash reference
    my $sum = 0;
    for my $num (keys %$href) {
        if ($start <= $num && $num <= $stop) {
            $sum += $href->{$num};
        }   
    }
    print "$_\t$sum\n";

}
close $fh or die $!;
```

The results from this were:

```
chr1    121087394   121087399   19099
chr1    121087820   121087822   5005
chr20   1934714     1934716     5311
chr3    108047283   108047284   3505
```

EDIT: The OP changed her inputs. I made a change in my last line of output to reflect this. She reports '5331' in the third line of the outout, but the correct number is '5311'